# Cannot get alert message from UpTime Check

Tags: monitoring, google-cloud-platform, uptime

I try to send alert message of UpTime checks through Slack and Email. I added channels in alerting and apply policy in UpTime check but I cannot get any message. How do I get these alert messages?

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that if the resource you are trying to monitor isn't publicly available, you must configure the resource's firewall to permit incoming traffic from the [uptime-check servers](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#before_you_begin).

Also I would recommend to check the full documentation that will guide you in the [uptime-check](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks) creation and configuration.